# javafx scrollpane how to disable focus

Tags: javafx

basically, i have this scrollpane and cant find a way to disable the "focus" (blue border):

[image]

as you can see setFocusTraversable isn't working as i expect (it works with other elements such as buttons):

```
@Getter private final VBox vbox = new VBox();
@Getter private final ScrollPane leftAreaPane = new ScrollPane(vbox);
private final Window window;

public LeftArea (Window window) {
    this.window = window;
}

public void config () {
    this.leftAreaPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    this.leftAreaPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    this.leftAreaPane.getStyleClass().add("left-area");
    this.leftAreaPane.setFocusTraversable(false);
    this.leftAreaPane.setTranslateY(Settings.getInstance().menuBarHeight + Settings.getInstance().topAreaHeight);
    this.leftAreaPane.setPrefWidth(Settings.getInstance().leftAreaWidth);
    this.leftAreaPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.subtract(this.window.scene.heightProperty(),
    Settings.getInstance().menuBarHeight + Settings.getInstance().topAreaHeight));
    this.window.group.getChildren().add(this.leftAreaPane);
    this.vbox.setFocusTraversable(false);
    this.vbox.setPrefWidth(this.leftAreaPane.getPrefWidth());
    this.vbox.setSpacing(10);
    this.vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    this.vbox.setStyle(Settings.getInstance().leftAreaStyle);
}
```

left area style is:

```
.left-area > .viewport {
     -fx-background-color: #525252;
}
```

Comment: Don't screenshot text, [add text as text, properly formatted](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/5-ways-to-embed-code-in-stack-overflow-8d9f38edf02c).

Comment: What styles you defined for "left-area" styleClass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with what @jewelsea mentioned. But if your question is to turn off the blue border (visual representation of focus) but still access the ScrollPane, then you can try the below solution.

You need to ensure to set the same styles to focused state, so that it will not show blue border.

Below is the code to demonstrate that:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ScrollPaneFocusDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        StackPane content = new StackPane();
        content.setMinSize(50,600);
        content.setStyle("-fx-background-color:linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, red);");
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(content);
        scrollPane.getStyleClass().add("left-pane");
        VBox.setVgrow(scrollPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        VBox layout = new VBox(10,new Button("Test 1"),scrollPane,new Button("Test 2"));
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300,200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("scrollpanefocus.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("ScrollPaneFocus Demo");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

And the css code is as below:

```
.left-pane,
.left-pane:focused{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-padding: 1;
}
```

*Note that we are not turning off the focus behaviour of ScrollPane. So the focused listener of ScrollPane and focusOwner listener of scene will still trigger when the ScrollPane is focused (technically ;-))*

Comment: it works as i expected, very thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

**Disable a control to disable its focus capability**

If you want to disable a node, so it can't be focused, then call [`setDisable`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisable(boolean)):

```
scrollPane.setDisable(true);
```

From the documentation for the associated [`disabled`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#disabledProperty()) property:

> A disabled Node does not receive mouse or key events.

This means you can't click on it or use keys to focus it, so it can't be focused and also won't display the blue outlined focus ring.

**FAQ**

> setFocusTraversable isn't working:

[`setFocusTraversable`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setFocusTraversable(boolean)) is working.  It just doesn't do what you think it does.  Read the documentation:

> Specifies whether this Node should be a part of focus traversal cycle. When this property is true focus can be moved to this Node and from this Node using regular focus traversal keys. On a desktop such keys are usually `TAB` for moving focus forward and `SHIFT+TAB` for moving focus backward. When a Scene is created, the system gives focus to a Node whose focusTraversable variable is true and that is eligible to receive the focus, unless the focus had been set explicitly via a call to `requestFocus()`.

So that has nothing to do with disabling focus.  It only disables focus switching to this node via focus traversal keys.  You can still click on and interact with a focusable node even if focus traversal is set to false, and when you click on the node, it will be focused.

**Example**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ScrollApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(new Group());
        scrollPane.setPrefViewportWidth(100);
        scrollPane.setPrefViewportHeight(100);
        scrollPane.setDisable(true);

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(scrollPane);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```